# Append path to filename

Tags: bash, find, rename

I have some pictures called test1.jpg in many subfolders. I want to essentially append the file's path to its name so there's no confusion.

sample path:

```
/tmp/xxx2016/folder123/folder2/folderxxx/test1.jpg
```

When I'm done I want the file to be renamed:

```
123_02_01_01.jpg
```

Can someone help me do this using find and mv commands. I am fairly new to bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

 find . -name '*.jpg' | grep test1
     newname="$(echo ${FILE} | grep -o "[0-9]*" | tr "\n" "_" | sed s/2016_//;s/_$/.jpg\n/;')"
     mv "${FILE}" "${newname}" ;
 done
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something to start you off with;

```
$ echo "/tmp/xxx2016/folder123/folder2/folderxxx/test1.jpg" | grep -o "[0-9]*" | tr "\n" "_" | sed 's/_$/.jpg\n/;'
2016_123_2_1.jpg
```

EDIT, skip 2016;

```
$ echo "/tmp/xxx2016/folder123/folder2/folderxxx/test1.jpg" | grep -o "[0-9]*" | tail -n +2 | tr "\n" "_" | sed 's/_$/.jpg\n/;'
123_2_1.jpg
```

or

```
$ echo "/tmp/xxx2016/folder123/folder2/folderxxx/test1.jpg" | grep -o "[0-9]*" | tr "\n" "_" | sed 's/2016_//;s/_$/.jpg\n/;'
123_2_1.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you! I see what that is doing and how to modify. Now I am wondering how to add to sed so that it would ignore 2016 at front. I tried modifying      sed 's/\/_$/.jpg\n/;' and it didnt give me exactly what I wanted

Comment: I added code to rename my files from a find but get EOF while matching error at newname line. Not sure what I'm missing to make it execute

Comment: I see no loop on the find, try; `find . -name '*.jpg' | grep test1 | while read aline; do` , also the first single quote is missing at start of sed.